# Is there better way to create lazy variable initialization?

Tags: python, variables, lazy-evaluation

I want to create code that initialize variable only when I really need it. But initializing in the regular way:

```
var = None

if var is None:
    var = factory()
var2 = var
```

Make too much noise in the code.

I tried to create fast solution but I feel there is better option. This is my solution that is fast but can't get parameters and use defaultdict for this.

```
def lazy_variable(factory):
    data = defaultdict(factory)
    return lambda: data['']

var = lazy_variable(a_factory)
var2 = var()
```

More questions:

- is there fast python container that holds only one variable?
- is there a way to return value without calling the function with parenthesis?

EDIT:

Please consider performance. I know i can create a class that can have this behavior, but it slower then the simple solution and also the default dict solution.

trying some of the solutions:

define:

```
import cachetools.func
import random

@cachetools.func.lru_cache(None)
def factory(i):
    return random.random()
```

and run:

```
%%timeit

for i in xrange(100):
    q = factory(i)
    q = factory(i)
```

got:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.63 ms per loop
```

naive:

```
%%timeit

for i in xrange(100):
    a = None
    if a is None:
        a = random.random()
    q = a
    q = a
```

got:

```
The slowest run took 4.71 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.8 µs per loop
```

I'm not sure what was cached

defaultdict solution:

```
%%timeit

for i in xrange(100):
    a = lazy_variable(random.random)
    q = a()
    q = a()
```

got:

```
The slowest run took 4.11 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 76.3 µs per loop
```

Tnx!

Comment: I am not sure if this fits your requirements, but take a look at [`descriptors`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-example).

Comment: That's help, but when i tried to use classes for the solution it wasn't fast as the solution iv'e found. class creation is slow and i need solution that's fits long for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think i found a nice and fast solution using generators:

```
def create_and_generate(creator):
    value = creator()
    while True:
        yield value    


def lazy_variable(creator):
    generator_instance = create_and_generate(creator)
    return lambda: next(generator_instance)
```

another fast solution is:

```
def lazy_variable(factory):
    data = []
    def f():
        if not data:
            data.extend((factory(),))
        return data[0]
    return f
```

but I thing the generator is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly then some of the functionality you are interested in is provided by `functools.lru_cache`:

```
import functools as ft

@ft.lru_cache(None)
def lazy():
    print("I'm working soo hard")
    return sum(range(1000))

lazy() # 1st time factory is called
# I'm working soo hard
# 499500
lazy() # afterwards cached result is used
# 499500
```

The decorated factory may also take parameters:

```
@ft.lru_cache(None)
def lazy_with_args(x):
    print("I'm working so hard")
    return sum((x+i)**2 for i in range(100))

lazy_with_args(3.4)
# I'm working so hard
# 363165.99999999994
lazy_with_args(3.4)
# 363165.99999999994
# new parametes, factory is used to compute new value
lazy_with_args(-1.2)
# I'm working so hard
# 316614.00000000006
lazy_with_args(-1.2)
# 316614.00000000006
# old value stays in cache
lazy_with_args(3.4)
# 363165.99999999994
```

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about instance variables, then yes - you can write your own wrapper and have it behave the way you want:

```
class LazyVar(object):

    def __init__(self, factory, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = "__value_" + str(id(self))  # internal store
        self.factory = factory
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            try:
                return getattr(instance, self.id)
            except AttributeError:
                value = self.factory(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
                setattr(instance, self.id, value)
                return value


def factory(name):
    print("Factory called, initializing: " + name)
    return name.upper()  # just for giggles


class TestClass(object):

    foo = LazyVar(factory, "foo")
    bar = LazyVar(factory, "bar")
```

You can test it as:

```
test = TestClass()
print("Foo will get initialized the moment we mention it")
print("Foo's value is:", test.foo)
print("It will also work for referencing, so even tho bar is not initialized...")
another_bar = test.bar
print("It gets initialized the moment we set its value to some other variable")
print("They, of course, have the same value: `{}` vs `{}`".format(test.bar, another_bar))
```

Which will print:

```
Foo will get initialized the moment we mention it
Factory called, initializing: foo
Foo's value is: FOO
It will also work for referencing, so even tho bar is not initialized...
Factory called, initializing: bar
It gets initialized the moment we set its value to some other variable
They, of course, have the same value: `BAR` vs `BAR`
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use the same trick for globally declared variables  as `__get__()` gets called only when accessed as instance vars.

Answer (score 1):

A simple container (but which needs the parentheses nevertheless) can be done e.g. like this:

```
class Container:
    UNDEF = object()

    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.data = Container.UNDEF
        self.factory = factory

    def __call__(self):
        if self.data is Container.UNDEF:
            self.data = self.factory()

        return self.data

# Test:

var = Container(lambda: 5)

print(var())
print(var())
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you *could* simply access `locals()` or `globals()` and type

```
var2 = locals().get('var', factory())
```

but I have never been in a situation where that would be useful, so you should probably evaluate why you want to do what you want to do.